# Регулярка для проверки на число :)

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

считываю строку

строка должна представлять число (int/double)

в качестве разделителя могут присутствовать оба разделителя(./,)

(пример: 123,123 == 123.123)

как проверить строку регулярным выражением, на то, что это число?

Comment: зачем регулярка? Чем `Double.TryParse()` не устраивает?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы не должны пользоваться регулярками для такой проверки. Хотя такая проверка была бы возможна, она будет слишком медленной и слишком сложной, а значит, подверженной ошибкам. Например, не так просто поймать максимальное число, которое всё ещё принадлежит типу `double`.

Делайте так:

```
var russianCI = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
if (double.TryParse("123,123", NumberStyles.Float, russianCI, out var v))
    Console.WriteLine(v);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Не число");
```

Разделитель зависит от выбранного языка (`CultureInfo`): например, для русского функция будет ожидать число в формате с запятой, а для английского — с точкой.

Comment: А если число задано вот так: 1d?

Comment: @AnatoliiBorodaiev: Это нестандартный формат чисел, не используемый обычными людьми. Для нестандартных форматов нужен нестандартный парсер. Например, вы можете отрезать суффикс `d`, и распарсить остальное при помощи `double.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

`bool result = Regex.IsMatch(input, "\d+[\.,]?\d*");`

Возможно, стоит учесть еще мантиссу и знак перед числом.

Comment: Минус не мой, но: такая регулярка примет число длиной в 1000 цифр.

Comment: @VladD, годное замечание